# Passing variable to second vc using didSelectItemAt in UICollectionView swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

So what I've been trying to do this whole time is basically get a master-detail flow through three layers rather than two. That is, I'm trying to create a master (home) screen-> category screen-> detail (particular) screen flow in my app.

To do this, I'm trying to get a particular category to load depending on what is selected on the first screen. After that, I'll just load that particular item into the detail screen.

I tried set it up so that on didSelectItemAt the categoryToLoad variable is set, it then prepares the segue, passing a variable to the loaded vc, and shows. The opened vs should handle the key and open the category associated.

Ex. I click "Some Videos". categoryToLoad is set to "Some Videos". The segue begins preparing. It reads the categoryToLoad as "Some Videos", sets categoryKey to "Videos". It sets the categoryName of the second vc to "Videos". The second vc loads [Videos.plist].

However, with the current code, although it does this all correctly, the pressing of the button causes its own segue so that when I use performSegue it causes two segues, the segue of the storyboard as well as the performSegue.

When I remove performSegue(it does the single segue that only shows my blank default storyboard, loading as "Default"). If I go back and try again, it loads correctly the original pressed category.

Eg. I press Videos, am shown Default. I got back, press Resources, am shown Videos.

There's something wrong with the order in which things are being done, but I'm new so I'm having a hard time figuring it out. Been here looking for a while.

```
class HomeViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    var categoryToLoad = ""
    ...
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        if segue.identifier == "toCategorySegue"{
            let catVC = segue.destination as! CategoryViewController
            var categoryKey = "Default"

            switch categoryToLoad {
            case "Some Videos"
                categoryKey = "Videos"
            case "Help Resources"
                categoryKey = "Resources"
            ...
            default:
                categoryKey = "Default"

            catViewController.categoryName = categoryKey
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                              didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){

        categoryToLoad = photos[indexPath.item].caption 
        // Returns the title of a particular item (E.g. "Contact Us")

        //alternatively, I also tried adding 
        //performSegue(withIdentifier("toCategorySegue", sender: self)) here

    ...
    }

class CategoryViewController: UICollectionViewController{
    var categoryName = ""
    // here the vc loads the data for its collection view from 
    // a plist named [categoryKey].pList
    ...
}
```